# Sum of two independent variables is binomial. Are they also binomial?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent non-negative integer random variables, such that $X+Y$ has binomial distribution. Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are also binomial.

I tried to just write the obvious equation, but it seems that this approach does not take me anywhere... Is there an easy way to see this result, without any tediuos computations?

Comment: Write down the obvious equation you tried. It is always advised to provide more details about your attempts before getting help here.

Comment: $P(X+Y = n) = \sum_{k=0}^n P(X = k)P(Y = n-k)$ is the equation

Comment: The proof looks like induction should work

Comment: You should be able to show if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with $X+Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ then $X \sim \text{Bin}(n_x,p)$ and $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n_y,p)$ with $n_x+n_y=n$ and notably the same $p$ as $X+Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $Z=X+Y$ is a Binomial $B(n,p)$

Because $X,Y$ are non-negative indepedent integer random variables, they must be restricted to $0\le X,Y\le n$.

Now, let $G_X(t)$ and $G_Y(t)$ be the [GF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of $X$ and $Y$.

Because of the above $G_X(t)$, $G_Y(t)$ are polinomial of degree at most $n$. And $G_Z(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$:

$$G_Z(t)= (1 -p +pz )^n = G_X(t)G_Y(t)$$

Because the polynomial is already factorized, (and we have the restriction $G(1)=1$) there must exist some $ 0 \le n_x \le n$ such that

$$ G_X(t)= (1 -p +pz )^{n_x}$$
$$ G_Y(t)= (1 -p +pz )^{n_y}$$

with $n_y = n- n_x$.

Then both $X,Y$ are Binomials with same parameter $p$ as $Z$.